# Java overflow and underflow , why no error or exception?

Tags: error-handling, overflow, underflow

Why Java creators decided not to throw any error or exception when overflow or underflow hapens considering the fact that such scenarios are usually lethal for any software.

Comment: what kind of overflow or underflow are you talking about? stack? buffer?
There are some such exceptions, for example 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/BufferOverflowException.html.


Besides, stack overflow error exists....
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html

Comment: I am talking about arithmetic overflow or underflow , say when we add two integers and the result is out of range of integer.